# PHP/Smarty Shop Script issue

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to get Shop-Script Free by Webasyst to display the same shopping cart on 2 different websites. I want to only use one admin section.

I can get the categories, product names, product counts, prices and layout to display properly on both websites but I can't get the product images to show up on the second website (they display fine on the 'main' website).

The code I need help with is in the if statements for the $product_info[7] and $product_info[5]. They are coming back as false (0) and are not displaying.

```
{if $product_info[7]}
<a href="index.php?productID={$product_info[11]}">
<img src="products_pictures/{$product_info[7]}" alt="{$product_info[1]|replace:'"':'& quot;'}" border=0 /><br />
{$smarty.const.MORE_INFO_ON_PRODUCT}
</a>
{else}
{if $product_info[5]}
<a href="index.php?productID={$product_info[11]}">
<img src="products_pictures/{$product_info[5]}" alt="{$product_info[1]|replace:'"':'&  quot;'}" border=0 />
{$smarty.const.MORE_INFO_ON_PRODUCT}
</a>
{/if}
{/if}
```

I've tried `{if $product_info[7] ne ''}` and `{if $product_info[7] ne NULL}`

Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why don't you use `{$product_info[1]|escape}` instead of the custom `replace` filter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that with Smarty you have to use isset to check for a null value.  So try this out:

```
{if isset($product_info[5]) && $product_info[5] != ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use dot-notation to index into arrays in smarty. So try this:

```
{if $product_info.7}
<a href="index.php?productID={$product_info.11}">
<img src="products_pictures/{$product_info.7}" alt="{$product_info.1|replace:'"':'& quot;'}" border=0 /><br />
{$smarty.const.MORE_INFO_ON_PRODUCT}
</a>
{else}
{if $product_info.5}
<a href="index.php?productID={$product_info.11}">
<img src="products_pictures/{$product_info.5}" alt="{$product_info.1|replace:'"':'&  quot;'}" border=0 />
{$smarty.const.MORE_INFO_ON_PRODUCT}
</a>
{/if}
{/if}
```

However I admit I have not tried it the way you are doing it.
I would recommend using an associative array though, instead of a numerically indexed one. The way Smarty is designed, it works much better if your indexes are named.